# Some workspace shortcuts do not work in Xfce

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, workspaces

I have four workspaces and eight shortcuts to change workspaces. The shortcuts are as follows.

[image: Workspace Shortcuts]

I have the four workspaces lined up in 2x2 grid in the Xfce Panel as follows.

[image: Workspaces and Workspace Switcher]

Even though I can switch workspaces with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> I can't switch workspaces with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

How can I switch to upper and bottom workspaces using shortcuts again?

Comment: @clearkimura, really? But I remember from prior use of *xfce* that the appearance of *workspace switcher* does in fact change the functional configuration as well as its appearance. Otherwise, what's the significance of the shortcuts if they don't have any of working?

Comment: +1 You are right, the "number of rows" indeed affect the workspaces layout as well (my bad). In fact, I just realized that I can reproduce the same issue--but I quickly managed to figure out what was wrong. I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause: "Show miniature view" was disabled

By default, Xfce has "Show miniature view" enabled already when the Workspace Switcher is first added to the panel. The workspace shortcuts do not seem to work when user has had the option disabled once--means one time only--afterwards.

To understand that, observe how the workspace shortcuts work according to the workspace layout--regardless of grid, horizontal, or vertical layout--in Xfce:

1. The "Show miniature view" is **enabled**, then the "Number of rows" is changed at any time, and then use workspace shortcuts (OK)
2. The "Show miniature view" is **disabled**, then the "Number of rows" is changed, and then use workspace shortcuts (FAIL)

The workaround for case 2: The "Show miniature view" is **enabled once again**, or **toggled (enabled and disabled in turn)**, then the shortcuts will work again.

In short, the "Show miniature view" seems to be the key factor that will apply the changes made to the desktop layout. That would explain why the workspace shortcuts did not work, given that changes made to desktop layout was not applied immediately.

**Clarification**: Looks like this is [Bug #10229](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10229):

> 10229 – Cannot switch multi-row-workspaces vertically via keyboard-shortcut unless chosen "miniature-preview"
>
> Reported by: Droids
>   Reported on: 2013-07-10
>   Version: 4.10.0
>   Target Milestone: Future

The bug was reported from version 4.10; however, this issue can be reproduced in earlier release as well. I had tested from Xfce 4.8 until Xfce 4.12 by running live session of Xubuntu 12.04 until 18.04 LTS releases in a virtual machine. I can also confirm the issue in Xfce 4.12 on a physical machine.

**TL;DR** The workspace shortcuts will follow the desktop layout, but Xfce does not apply the desktop layout immediately unless "Show miniature view" is enabled at least once. This is a known bug since 2013.

Comment: **You're right!** I disabled *miniature view* because in multiple-row view, it is not clear to see. But I just have since then went back to single row. Just now, after reading your answer, I reverted back to *two-row* view and **it works**! Whatever may be the case, bug or otherwise, thank you! for taking the time to test and answer.

Comment: @klaus Looks like this is a known bug since 2013, which I did not really realize until recently. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it doen't work.
you can ask here :[forum xfce](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php)
But I think it's a bug and you can report it here :[bug xfce](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/enter_bug.cgi)